# How to model my entities with relations in core-data for my case?

Tags: ios, core-data, orm

I really need some help solving this little puzzle in my app.

Case: I have, lets say 4 entities in Core-Data:

- MixColors (consist of 3 colors from ColorA,B and C. And many of them)
- ColorA
- ColorB
- ColorC

The user chooses 3 colors(A,B,C), and stores the result in MixColors. The 3 colors is just the ID from the color entities, the indexed ID (primary key). Entity mixcolors consist of 'many' combinations for those colors.

**My bad solution:** I can easily make the model without relationships.. but I prefer relations in core-data.

**Problem:** So how could I achieve this? 
Should I combine ColorA,B,C into one entity: Color - and then make a single relationsship but I see some problems for the index IDs? So what's the best way to model this case in core-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core data you don't have to worry about IDs at all, it's all taken care of for you. Maybe try this:

```
Palette < ---- >> Color
```

You only need 2 objects and a one to many relationship between palette objects and color objects. In practice this will mean a Palette object will have a property called Colors, which will be an `NSSet` of color objects. If the color objects have to also keep their order then add a property for that, like 'order' that stores a number. You can then fetch them in that order.

Comment: I have the order property. I also understand the Palette <-->> Color. But what do you mean with Palette (MixColors?) object and 'NSSet of color'?

Comment: In a CoreData one-to-many relationships, it handles the many side as an `NSSet`. so you'd use `palette.colors` to get an NSSet of Color objects  belonging to the Palette object.

Comment: Okay so the 'colors' that is a property.. is infact the relationship itself? im not sure I fully get your other words. Can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: Another issue, I need ID's to keep track of the colors. So what would you recommand Entity Palette's attributes should be?

Comment: Yes `colors` is the name of the relationship which becomes a property of the `Palette` class, this means the `Color` objects get a property called 'palette' (or whatever you name it) which is the other side of that relationship. As for IDs give the palettes a name or key attribute.

Comment: Cool now im with you. But isn't Palette <-->> Color wrong? Colors don't need to have a palette relation. We can have colors that isn't saved in 'Palette' - so palette can be empty.

Comment: Well, then all you have are color objects. Don't you need to store combinations of colors?

Comment: Yes but I start only with color objects and users can choose to store combinations of them after. So how would you make this with entities and relations?

Comment: If you set up a relation in CoreData it's not a requirement to always be there. You can create color objects as often as you like. When you need to store a color mix, then create a palette object and then add the chosen colors to it. If you create your model plus the relationships, CoreData adds the methods for adding and removing child objects. It'll be something `like `addColorsObject:(id)color` and `addColorsObjects:(NSSet *)colors`.

Comment: Okay I did a mix of my start-point solution using one-to-many and the other way around with your relation example. Andrew: Thanks for your time, help and thoughts. Always good to share some solutions with others :)